# Reactjs working with sockets: rerender when socket receive a message

Tags: javascript, websocket, coffeescript, reactjs

I'm try to implement something like chat application with usage of websockets. But when websocket got a message, no components are rerendering. Please review my code

```
# The main ancestor, chat application
@Chat = React.createClass
  componentWillMount: ->
    @setState signals: [] # the list of signals received by websockets

    socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:19108')
    socket.onmessage = (event) =>
      @state.signals.push { message: event.data, direction: 'in' }
      console.log @state.signals # it regularly write a message to console after receiving socket message

    @setState socket: socket
  render: ->
    <div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <SignalList signals={@state.signals} /> # I pass a signals here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

$ ->
  React.render(<Chat />, document.getElementById('container'))
```

Signal list now try just to show changes of `props`, but with no success. It's still an empty array

```
@SignalList = React.createClass
  render: ->
    <div>{ @props }</div>
```

I want `props` rerendering after each message received by websockets. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't mutate `@state` directly, but instead use [`setState`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) to enqueue a state update which, once performed, will cause the component to re-render. You should consider `@state` and its value as read-only most of the time.

In your case, replace

```coffeescript
@state.signals.push { message: event.data, direction: 'in' }
```

with

```coffeescript
@setState signals: @state.signals.concat([{ message: event.data, direction: 'in' }])
```

Unlike `Array::push`, [`Array::concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/concat) has the benefit of not mutating the source array, which means `@state.signals` stays unchanged until the state update has been performed.

Answer (score 2):

In the `onmessage` callback, you are manipulating `state.signals` directly rather than calling `setState`.

Try:

```
socket.onmessage = (event) =>
  signals = @state.signals
  signals.push { message: event.data, direction: 'in' }
  @setState signals: signals
```

Comment: Thanks! But I think, another one example is shorter

Comment: Glad I could help at least :)